# Using Spivak's definition to show a volume element

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, tensors, volume, orthonormal

Let $V$ be a vector space of dimension $2n$, $T$ be an inner product on $V$, $v_1, v_2, \cdots, v_{2n}$ be an orthonormal basis and $v_1^*, v_2^*, \cdots v_{2n}^*$ be the dual basis. Let $$\omega = v_1^* \wedge v_2^* + v_3^* \wedge v_4^* + \cdots + v_{2n-1}^* \wedge v_{2n}^*$$ be an alternating 2-tensor. Prove that $$\frac{1}{n!}\omega^n = \frac{1}{n!}\omega \wedge \omega \wedge \cdots \wedge \omega$$ is a volume element of V, where there are $n$ copies of $\omega$ in the product.

Also prove that there do not exist linear functions $\gamma_1, \cdots , \gamma_{2n-2} \in V^*$ such that $$\omega = \gamma_1 \wedge \gamma_2 + \gamma_3 \wedge \gamma_4 + \cdots + \gamma_{2n-3} \wedge \gamma_{2n-2}.$$

Definition of a Volume Element from Spivak: If an orientation $\mu$ for $V$ has also  been given, it follows that there is  a  unique $\omega$ $\in \wedge^n V$ such that $w(v_1, ... ,v_n) = 1$  whenever $v_1, ... ,v_n$ is an orthonormal basis such that $[v_1, ... ,v_n] = \mu$. This unique $\omega$ is  called the volume element of $V$, determined by the inner product $T$ and orientation $\mu$.

I am given no orientation for $V$, so how might I go about finding one or is it even necessary given what is offered in the question. Also, the question implies that there are many volume elements of V, yet the definition says it is unique.

Comment: There are always exactly two possible orientations on a vector space; also note that if you reverse your orientation then the sign of the volume element will change. In your hypothesis "... $v_1, \dots, v_{2n}$ be an orthonormal basis..." perhaps you should add the extra hypothesis "... $v_1, \dots, v_{2n}$ be a positively oriented orthonormal basis". Anyway, as far as the computations go, if you're stuck, I suggest you try out a small case, like $n=2$ and then $n=3$, to get an idea, and then try to generalize.

Comment: Okay, I think I am struggling to determine what computation I should be doing. Is it necessary to just directly compute \omega(v_1, ..., v_2n)?

Comment: Notice that the $\omega$ in your question and the $\omega$ in Spivak's definition are different things. You're given a certain definition of $\omega$ in your question, and you're asked to prove something about $\dfrac{1}{n!}\omega^n$, so this is the thing you should calculate: take the $\omega$ in your question, wedge product it $n$-times with itself and then see what you get.